# Dificuldade em trabalhar com arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho esse código que retorna normalmente usando a instrução `switch`

```js
function getLetter(s) {

    switch(true) {
        case 'aeiou'.includes(s):
            console.log("A");
            break;
        case 'bcdfg'.includes(s):
            console.log("B");
            break;
        case 'hjklm'.includes(s):
            console.log("C");
            break;
        case 'npqrstvwxyz'.includes(s):
            console.log("D");
            break;
    }
}
getLetter('i'); //Retorna A
getLetter('f'); //Retorna B
getLetter('k'); //Retorna C
getLetter('p'); //Retorna D
```

Fiz essa mesma função só que utilizando `arrays`

```js
function getLetter(s) {

    const A = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    const B = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f,', 'g'];
    const C = ['h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'];
    const D = ['n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
    if(s == A.includes(s)){
        console.log("A");
    } else if (s == B.includes(s)) {
        console.log("B");
    } else if(s == C.includes(s)) {
        console.log("C");
    } else {
        console.log("D");
    }

}
/*Tentei dessa forma bastante semelhante, porém
  passando conchetes e continua retornando a letra D

    if(s == A.includes([s])){
        console.log("A");
    } else if (s == B.includes([s])) {
        console.log("B");
    } else if(s == C.includes([s])) {
        console.log("C");
    } else {
        console.log("D");
    }
*/

//Não passa em nenhuma das condições
getLetter('i'); //Retorna D 
getLetter('f'); //Retorna D
getLetter('k'); //Retorna D
getLetter('p'); //Retorna D
```

Pesquisei se existia realmente o método `includes` em `array`, e sim possui normalmente de acordo com a [documentação da mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains), então por que quando vou fazer a comparação de `s == A.includes(s)` ou `s == A.includes([s])` retorna `D`?

Para maiores detalhes do que o exercício está pedindo acessar o site [hackrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/js10-switch/problem)

Comment: A.includes([s]) retorna true or false, estás a perguntar se s é igual a true ou false, vai dar sempre D dessa forma.

Comment: Certo, mais então qual a diferença de https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains para isso https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes sendo que ambos retornam `true` ou `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa comparar `s == A.includes([s])` basta usar `A.includes(s)`, porque o `includes` já é uma condição de comparação.

O `includes` funciona como um *contém*. Como: O conjunto `A` contém `s` ... se esta condição é verdadeira, irá entrar na condição informada.

Veja abaixo funcionando?

```js
function getLetter(s) {

    const A = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    const B = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f,', 'g'];
    const C = ['h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'];
    const D = ['n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
    if(A.includes(s)){
        console.log("A");
    } else if (B.includes(s)) {
        console.log("B");
    } else if(C.includes(s)) {
        console.log("C");
    } else {
        console.log("D");
    }
}

//Não passa em nenhuma das condições
getLetter('i');
getLetter('f');
getLetter('k'); 
getLetter('p');
```